# Styling specific table cell using Vue.js and v-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a table that is binded to data using Vue.js. For each player, create a row (TR). For each report within the player, create a cell (TD). That is working fine, but I would like to add a class to the last cell of the current report ID.

So...

```
<tr>
    <td></td>                     //rptID = 1
    <td></td>                     //rptID = 1
    <td></td>                     //rptID = 1
    <td class="lastOfRptID"></td> //rptID = 1
    <td></td>                     //rptID = 2
    <td class="lastOfRptID"></td> //rptID = 2
</tr>
```

Here is my example code:

```js
var objArr = [
    {
        playerID: 1,
        rpts: [
            {rptID: 1,score: 1},
            {rptID: 1,score: 2},
            {rptID: 1,score: 3},
            {rptID: 1,score: 4},
            {rptID: 2,score: 1},
            {rptID: 2,score: 2}
        ]
    },
    {
        playerID: 2,
        rpts: [
            {rptID: 1,score: 5},
            {rptID: 1,score: 6},
            {rptID: 1,score: 7},
            {rptID: 1,score: 8},
            {rptID: 2,score: 3},
            {rptID: 2,score: 4}
        ]
     }
];
var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#rpts',
    data: {
        title: 'reports',
        reports: objArr
    }
});
```

```css
table {
    width:99%;
    height:20px;
}
td {
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.11.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<table id="rpts">
    <tr v-repeat="reports">
        <td v-repeat="rpts | orderBy 'rptID'">{{score}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would first preprocess your data by running through each of the rpts and adding a flag to the row if it is the last of that report (example code using lodash):

```
_.forEach(objArr, function (obj, index) {
    var previousRpt = null;
    _.forEach(obj.rpts, function (rpt, index) {
        if (previousRpt == null || previousRpt.rptId == rpt.rptId) {
            previousRpt.last = false;
        }
        rpt.last = true;
        previousRpt = rpt;
    });
});
```

And use that new value like this:

```
<table id="rpts">
    <tr v-repeat="reports">
        <td v-repeat="rpts | orderBy 'rptID'"
            v-class="lastOfRptID: last">{{score}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```